# replace differently for different occurrences with sed

Tags: bash, sed

Probably an easy question but I am not able to figure it out. How can I use sed to replace differently for different occurrences?

I will give an example:

```
a="2012_01_01_05_05_05"
```

desired output:

```
mod_a="2012-01-01 05:05:05"
```

the only thing I know how to do with sed is:

```
mod_a=`echo $a | sed 's/_/ /g'`
```

I could do this by removing the "_", transforming it to an array, and create a new expression based on each element, but it would be less elegant.

Comment: you cannot achieve this by replacing one character at a time (technically you can, but that's going to be a brittle solution). instead, replace the whole date string in one step.

Comment: Related: [Sed: Replace N first occurrences of a character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21178/40596)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple sed solution:

```
sed 's/_/-/;s/_/-/;s/_/ /;s/_/:/g' <<< "$a"
```

It replaces the first and the second `_` by `-`, the third `_` by a space and the remaining ones by a `:`.

Comment: I think this is definitely the simpler solution and using sed. In any case all solutions work!

Comment: I like particularly this answer because you can do it differently for just the few first occurrences and globally for the remain.

Answer (score 3):

this could be the way

```
mod_a=`echo $a | awk -F_ '{print $1"-"$2"-"$3,$4":"$5":"$6}'`
```

Comment: +1 This is simplest but OP already knows about it and wants a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this GNU sed command,

```
$ echo '2012_01_01_05_05_05' | sed -r 's/_/-/g;s/^(.*)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$/\1 \2:\3:\4/g'
2012-01-01 05:05:05
```

It replaces all the occurrences of `_` with `-`. From the output it again divides the numbers according to the `-` and stored it into groups. This groups are backreferenced in the replacement part  and formatted according to our desired output.

For your case,

```
$ mod_a=$(echo $a | sed -r 's/_/-/g;s/^(.*)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$/\1 \2:\3:\4/g')
$ echo $mod_a
2012-01-01 05:05:05
```

Answer (score 1):

You’ve tagged your question `bash`. If you have GNU Bash why on earth you are trying to use `sed` to do such a simple thing?

```
$ a="2012_01_01_05_05_05"
$ IFS='_' read Y m d H M S <<< "$a"
$ mod_a="$Y-$m-$d $H:$M:$S"
$ echo "$mod_a"
2012-01-01 05:05:05
```

There is nothing elegant in a mess of slashes and dashes which is native to `sed` but ’write-only’ for human.

Comment: you assumed more than I said in the question. In this specific case it is in fact a date, although the question is suppose to be more general than that. you can have other than "_" between the numbers, you may which to change only one occurrence in a different way, it may even not be reasonable to manually say how many elements you have. your answer works and is simpler for this particular but not all.

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro The total number of elements was not specified here – you’ve probably confused `read` with `set` – `read` puts to the last var all what remains (to the end of the line). If you do not know what char definitely delimits the string, you can list them all – `IFS` variable is a set of possible separators, i. e. when `IFS='_-:'` a line would be split by underline or hyphen or colon.